# How to align buttons uniformly in a tool strip?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, toolstrip

I have a tool strip container in which i have a tool strip.Inside the tool strip i have added three buttons. These buttons are laid out in the vertical tool strip one over another. The distance between the last button and bottom of tool strip is greater than the distance between two buttons. How do i reduce it so that all the buttons look equally distributed in the tool strip?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout: [How to: Change the Spacing and Alignment of ToolStrip Items in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce23khbk%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you looking to shorten the length of ToolStrip or equally distribute the buttons? Also, what `LayoutStyle` are you using?